# How can I convince my professor that I did not copy from another student?

Tags: computer-science, cheating, code

I am a computer science major and I was given a zero grade for having identical code to another student. I did not copy or share the code with anyone. The professor warned us that copying code from online sources or having overly similar code to another student will be punished. However, I did not copy or share the code and the professor don't seem to trust me because the code was identical. What can I do to convince/prove that it is my own work?

Comment: How many lines of the code?

Comment: He did not specify but said "code identical to code submitted by another student".

Comment: How many lines you wrote?

Comment: I wrote about 17 lines excluding line spacing.

Comment: Did you use the teaching materials?

Comment: I fully wrote the code myself and used the textbook for reference.

Comment: For plagiarism offences, do your university's regulations have a "beyond reasonable doubt" standard of proof or a "balance of probabilities" standard of proof?

Comment: Do you have any explanation how your code could be identical to another student's without you violating any rules? Same source (yours is cited)? Could they have had access to your code? Copied the files or photographed the screen? Is the code so absolutely obvious that only one way exists to write it (with 17 lines, this is difficult to believe)? Without a plausible route for incidental (from your perspective) match I think you will have a very difficult time to prove your innocence.

Comment: You wrote 17 lines of code. We don't know how many lines are supposedly the same. With 17 lines of simple code, it is quite possible to have 5 or 6 identical lines. I actually had a colleague once whose style was quite exactly the same as mine. The first time I noticed was looking at some code, it looked exactly as if I had written it, but couldn't remember it. With this guy, both of us writing 17 identical lines of code would be not unusual. Emacs: In this example, there were thousands of ways to write the code, but we two would tend to write it identical.

Comment: Did you check the code into Github or another source code repository before turning it in? Github repos are public by default.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs In your run-off-the-mill programming assignment, especially with a textbook reference, coincidental identity in 17 lines of code is not too wild, like gnasher729 says. Even more so in languages like C where some of these lines are just brackets. Think an assignment such as "given a list of strings, find a sum of all indices of words with the most a's in them" or something silly like that they love to give to students. Large part of the creativity causing potential differences will boil down to choosing variable names from `i`, `k`, `x`, `n`, `acc` or what have you...

Comment: @gnasher729 Quite possible. I also have a very dominant programming style that rubs off on people that I work with intensely. However, it is not clear that OP has such a relation with the other student. Sometimes, style is facilitated by the specific problem setting. As someone who has to detect plagiarism etc., however, some coincidences are too much to believe. Esp. if there are more than two cases. Let's put it this way - I believe an incidental similarity more strongly when the submissions are strong and have 'personality' (so to say) than when they are run-off-the-mill solutions.

Comment: @gnasher729 Mediocre or weak students do not usually have a strong sense of style; here, I expect a lot more variation if not confined by the problem setting. Anyway, it is rarely provable beyond reasonable doubt.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like exactly the sort of situation where university appeals processes, or "grievance" processes as they are sometimes called, *can* help. Whether they *would* help in your situation, or merely strain relationships, is something only you can judge. In deciding whether to initiate an appeal, I suggest you consider:

1. The likely university-wide effect (if any) of your professor believing that you cheated.
2. The value of the assignment for which you have received a 0 grade.

If you are at risk of being suspended from the degree course by the university administration because of your professor's belief, then that would weigh in favor of a rapid appeal. If your professor's beliefs have no carry-over effect, that might weigh against an appeal.

If the assignment forms a significant part of the course grade of an essential course, that again weighs in favor of an appeal. A small proportion of overall grade, or an irrelevant elective course, would weight against it.

Lastly, there are the consequences of an appeal itself, which might not be to your liking, *even if you succeed*! For example, it might sour your relationships with the professor, and that might be important to you.

In the end, only you can judge.

There is one last thing, which is actually a question: Is there any possibility that the other student saw your work and copied it? You might be able to judge that if you are in a position to know the emotional reaction of the other student to having likewise received a 0 grade.